# Settings-like array of NSString objects

Tags: objective-c

I'm only starting with Objective-C and it's still hard for me to do some pretty basic things. Here's what I want to achieve - I need to create a class that would hold all static data of my application which I guess could be represented with a number of NSString ** arrays, such as this one:

```
NSString *animalNames[NUM_ANIMALS] = {@"fox", @"wolf", @"elephant", @"giraffe"};
```

I want to be able to access these arrays in a static way from anywhere in my application. Something like this:

```
StaticData.animalNames[1]
```

How would I accomplish this in terms of @property, @interface, @synthesize and all this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to create a class that would hold all static data of my application

Here's an example of what you are talking about.  It's a basic singleton class with a static array of your animals.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo:NSObject
+ (id)sharedFoo;
- (NSArray *)animals;
@end

@implementation Foo

static NSArray *animals;

+ (void)initialize {
    animals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fox",@"wolf",@"giraffe",@"liger",nil];
}

+ (id)sharedFoo {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Foo *cSharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ cSharedInstance = [[Foo alloc] init]; });
    return cSharedInstance;
}

- (NSArray *)animals {
    return animals;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSLog(@"Animals = %@",[[Foo sharedFoo] animals]);

}
```

This application logs the following to the console:

> 2012-10-08 10:01:46.814 Untitled[77085:707] Animals = (
>       fox,
>       wolf,
>       giraffe,
>       liger )

EDIT:

If you favor the dot syntax/property notation, you could just implement the following in the class interface:

```
@property (readonly) NSArray *animals;
```

which would let you write:

```
[Foo sharedFoo].animals
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about singleton, but typing something like [[Foo sharedFoo] animals][1] each time I wanted to access a static var seemed like a burden.

Comment: You could make the accessor a class method. `+[Foo animals]` `+(NSArray *)animals { return animals; }`

Comment: I have one criticism of this otherwise perfect answer.  You should create the shared instance like this:  `cSharedInstance = [[Foo alloc] init];`.   The reason being that, if you have a subclass of `Foo` called say `Bar`and you call `[Bar sharedFoo]` your shared object will actually be a `Bar` which might give you unexpected behaviour depending on how it overrides `Foo`s other methods. Upvoted anyway

Comment: Also, you don't need `@property` to use dot syntax, but I think `-animals` should be declared as a property whether or not you do use dot syntax.

Comment: JeremyP - thanks for the catch and good point, will edit.  @devmiles.com welcome to ObjC - eventually the square brackets will become 2nd nature.

Comment: I didn't understand your comments about having to declare animals as a property...

Comment: I noted in your OP, you wanted to do something like `StaticData.animalNames[1]` so declaring a property would let you use similar notation to get to the animals.  JeremyP commented that property declaration wasn't necessary to achieve this.  However, I could not get it to compile without explicitly declaring a property.

Comment: Strange, because similar code compiles for me but doesn't work since [sharedFoo animals] returns an empty array.